# MySQL how to create a view with a subquery?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I would like to create a view called OrderSummary that contains CUSTOMER.FirstName, CUSTOMER.LastName, INVOICE.InvoiceDate and the invoice total (calculated by determining the sum of INVOICE_ITEM.Quantity multiplied by SERVICE.ServicePrice). I want to use a subquery to determine the invoice total. Thanks for the help.

```
CREATE VIEW OrderSummaryView AS
    SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, i.InvoiceDate
FROM CUSTOMER c, INVOICE i, SERVICE s  
WHERE c.CustomerID = i.InvoiceID  
AND c.CustomerID = s.ServiceID; 
SELECT sum(UnitPrice) * Quantity AS InvoiceTotal
FROM        SERVICE, INVOICE_ITEM
WHERE       SERVICE.ServiceID = invoice_item.InvoiceID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should work first on your select statement to include join specific syntax

```
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, i.InvoiceDate
FROM CUSTOMER c
JOIN INVOICE i ON c.CustomerID = i.InvoiceID 
JOIN INVOICE_ITEM ii ON ii.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID 
JOIN SERVICE s ON ii.ServiceID = s.ServiceID;
```

then we can add your other sub query

```
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, i.InvoiceDate, t.InvoiceTotal
FROM CUSTOMER c
JOIN INVOICE i ON c.CustomerID = i.InvoiceID 
JOIN INVOICE_ITEM ii ON ii.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID 
JOIN SERVICE s ON ii.ServiceID = s.ServiceID
JOIN
(   SELECT SUM(UnitPrice) * Quantity AS InvoiceTotal, i.InvoiceID
    FROM SERVICE s
    JOIN INVOICE_ITEM i ON i.InvoiceID = s.ServiceID
    GROUP BY i.InvoiceID
) as t ON t.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID;
```

one thing that looks kinda fishy is the fact that `customerid = invoiceid = serviceid`
are you sure that all of those are the correct pk -> fk relationships?

to create a view with a subview you have to do it in two steps

```
CREATE VIEW cust_inv_serv AS 
    SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, i.InvoiceDate, i.InvoiceID
    FROM CUSTOMER c
    JOIN INVOICE i ON c.CustomerID = i.InvoiceID 
    JOIN INVOICE_ITEM ii ON ii.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID 
    JOIN SERVICE s ON ii.ServiceID = s.ServiceID;

CREATE VIEW OrderSummaryView AS 
    SELECT v.FirstName, v.LastName, v.InvoiceDate, v.InvoiceID, SUM(UnitPrice) * Quantity AS InvoiceTotal
    FROM SERVICE s
    JOIN INVOICE_ITEM i ON i.InvoiceID = s.ServiceID
    JOIN cust_inv_serv v ON v.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
    GROUP BY i.InvoiceID;
```

Comment: I would also suggest asking about the primary key/foreign key issue -- Is the `CustomerId` really the same as the `InvoiceId` and `ServiceId`?

Comment: @pbnjenni why do you want to make this a view? all you have to do is put the create view before the query like before `CREATE VIEW OrderSummaryView AS SELECT...`

Comment: @pbnjenni it looks like invoice should join on CustomerID and service should join to invoice_item service id.. I'll edit my answer with what looks like the correct answer

Comment: Can mySQL not have a subquery in a view? I got the following error: Error Code: 1349. View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: @pbnjenni ok I updated with a way to make a view with a subview.. you have to make it in two queries. subqueries are not allowed in them

Comment: @pbnjenni sure thing. make sure your joins are correct. since I cant see the data its hard for me to be sure.. but it looks correct from my end. good luck! I threw you a +1 on the question :)